# Where I can find a java source code to do devirtualisation and inlining benchmarks for based Java ahead of time compiler?

Tags: java, optimization, compiler-construction, benchmarking, inlining

I have devloped whole global optimisations like devirtualisation and inlining  as a contribution  to the MobiVM project which is a fork of RoboVM ,when it 's came to do benchmarkes I now that test this kind of optimisations in simple or small applications will not take effect because inlining and devirtualisation specialy is related to the amount of virutual calls used in a program.Were I can find java source codes to do such a benchamrk or How to write such ones to prove the benefits of my optimisations.

Comment: Most large Java programs would be candidates, right?  Benchmark some of them, and see which ones benefit more / less from your changes, then investigate why.

Comment: Where I can find this large programs ?any link please?note that swing and  JavaFX are not supported.